# Is it possible to insert a foreign key value as it is created?

Tags: sql, sql-server, foreign-keys

Example tables for  SQL Server.

- **MainRecords** (`id, record`)
- **AuxRecords** (`mainRecords_id, record`)
- **SourceRecords** (`record1, record2`)

`MainRecords.id` is a self incrementing primary identity key.

Is it possible to select from `SourceRecords` and insert into `MainRecords` and `AuxRecords` at the same time such that `MainRecords.record = record1`, `AuxRecords.record = record2`, and `AuxRecords.mainRecords_id = MainRecords.id` all in a single statement?

EDIT:

Based on tip from below, I tried this...

```
DECLARE @MainRecords table(id int PRIMARY KEY IDENTITY, record varchar(5))
DECLARE @AuxRecords table(mainRecords_id int, record varchar(5))
DECLARE @SourceRecords table(record1 varchar(5), record2 varchar(5))

INSERT @SourceRecords VALUES ('a', 'a')
INSERT @SourceRecords VALUES ('a', 'b')
INSERT @SourceRecords VALUES ('a', 'c')
INSERT @SourceRecords VALUES ('b', 'a')
INSERT @SourceRecords VALUES ('b', 'b')
INSERT @SourceRecords VALUES ('b', 'c')
INSERT @SourceRecords VALUES ('c', 'a')
INSERT @SourceRecords VALUES ('c', 'b')
INSERT @SourceRecords VALUES ('c', 'c')

INSERT INTO @MainRecords (record)
  OUTPUT inserted.id, @SourceRecords.record2
  INTO @AuxRecords (mainRecords_id, record)
SELECT record1 FROM @SourceRecords

select * from @MainRecords
select * from @AuxRecords
```

But unfortunately get error:

```
Msg 137, Level 16, State 1, Line 16
Must declare the scalar variable "@SourceRecords".
```

If I change those table type variables into real tables I get the error:

```
Msg 4104, Level 16, State 1, Line 3
The multi-part identifier "SourceRecords.record2" could not be bound.
```

Below works fine, but obviously it isn't a complete solution. I'm just showing it to demonstrate that my syntax is correct.

```
INSERT INTO @MainRecords (record)
  OUTPUT inserted.id --, @SourceRecords.record2
  INTO @AuxRecords (mainRecords_id) --, record)
SELECT record1 FROM @SourceRecords
```

So... unless there is some trick I am missing, it seems like `OUTPUT` is a dead end solution for this problem.

The other suggestions of creating views or empty tables with triggers are not a "single statement" solution to the problem. Moreover, they add obscurity, whereas adding some extra columns and using a stored procedure is equally complex but more obvious and straightforward.

Comment: Why "*in a single statement*"?  Just use a stored procedure with Transactions, which is how you should be doing this stuff anyway.

Comment: the OUTPUT clause may be able to work for you.  You don't really provide enough schema info.  with `OUTPUT` you can generally return a result set, insert/update/delete one table and insert into a another table in the same statement.  There are limitations on column availability.  It would be far easier to write multiple statements within a transaction, however, even doing that, the `OUTPUT` statement is necessary to capture a set of generated identities.

Comment: @RBarryYoung a proc with transactions is "how [I] should be doing this stuff" *if* there is no more elegant way. IMHO, a single statement *can*, in theory, be more elegant. I've edited my question to show how close I got to a very elegant solution, but it unfortunately doesn't work, it seems. Furthermore, you'll see that what you suggest will not work in my precise example unless I use a cursor, or temp table, or add some new columns, etc; all a bit messy compared to what I hoped would be possible, but seems the only choice.

Comment: @DG: No, even if you *can* do it with a single statement *and* that's the best way to to do, it should *still* be in a stored procedure and wrapped in transaction-handling.

Comment: @RBarryYoung I'm no SQL guru, but AFAIK, you don't need transaction handling for a single statement, so going to have to disagree pending possible future evidence. And as far as idea that things "should" be in SP... well most often, I agree, but NOT *always*. In any case, I seek a single statement solution and by now I think adequately explained why. It would just be nice if the OUTPUT would let me include columns from the SELECT. That would be very handy in some circumstances.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**community wiki**

there isn't enough info in the question to write code to solve the question.  So, **here is a "generic" output clause example**, which does not relate at all to this question, other than to show how OUTPUT can be used:

**this will delete, insert, and return multiple rows in a single statement**

```
DECLARE @OldTable table(col1 int, col2    varchar(5), col3 char(5), col4     datetime)
DECLARE @NewTable table(col1 int, column2 varchar(5), col3 int    , col_date char(23), extravalue int, othervalue varchar(5))
INSERT @OldTable VALUES (1 , 'AAA' ,'A'  ,'1/1/2010'           )
INSERT @OldTable VALUES (2 , 'BBB' ,'12' ,'2010-02-02 10:11:22')
INSERT @OldTable VALUES (3 , 'CCC' ,null ,null                 )
INSERT @OldTable VALUES (4 , 'B'   ,'bb' ,'2010-03-02'         )

DELETE @OldTable           --<<<alter table 1
    OUTPUT DELETED.col1    --<<<alter table 2
          ,DELETED.col2
          ,CASE
               WHEN ISNUMERIC(DELETED.col3)=1 THEN DELETED.col3 
               ELSE NULL END
          ,DELETED.col4
          ,CONVERT(varchar(5),DELETED.col1)+'!!'
        INTO @NewTable (col1, column2, col3, col_date, othervalue)
    OUTPUT 'Rows Deleted: ', DELETED.* --<<<returns a result set
    WHERE col1 IN (2,4)

SELECT * FROM @NewTable
```

OUTPUT:

```
               col1        col2  col3  col4
-------------- ----------- ----- ----- -----------------------
Rows Deleted:  2           BBB   12    2010-02-02 10:11:22.000
Rows Deleted:  4           B     bb    2010-03-02 00:00:00.000

(2 row(s) affected)

col1        column2 col3        col_date                extravalue  othervalue
----------- ------- ----------- ----------------------- ----------- ----------
2           BBB     12          Feb  2 2010 10:11AM     NULL        2!!
4           B       NULL        Mar  2 2010 12:00AM     NULL        4!!

(2 row(s) affected)
```

Comment: You get an up-vote for the tip and teaching me something new, but it seems to not be a correct answer. See my edited question, based on your tip. Maybe you can see a flaw in my reasoning. (As a side note, IMHO, my original question does provide "enough info... to write code" if one makes some fairly commonsense assumptions, but the edited question is note more clear.)

Comment: you can not include `@SourceRecords.record2` in your OUTPUT clause, only columns from the inserted table are permitted

Comment: I've accepted this answer. It's not spot on, but was the best provided. AFAIK, no spot-on answer is possible.

Answer (score 0):

@DG you cannot modify multiple tables in a single statement.   As @RBarryYoung suggests you should do this sort of thing using a Stored Procedure and a transaction.  Another more extreme option would be to create a view on MainRecords and AuxRecords that joins the rows together, then create a before trigger on the view that splits it into two inserts, one against each base table. Your client could then do a single insert to the view.  All in all, I think the Stored Procedure / transaction approach is more obvious.

Comment: you can modify multiply multiple tables in a single statement, look at the `OUTPUT INTO` clause.

Comment: @KM good point on OUTPUT INTO.  Didn't think of it here because the AuxRecords table needs values that don't exist in MainRecords.

Comment: I don't remember what I used to do before the OUTPUT caluse!  I find it impossible to work with multiple rows and identity columns without it.

Answer (score 0):

From the practical point of view, @BStateham and @RBarryYoung gave you correct and complete answers. However, if this is a technical question where you only want to know whether it is possible, I would say: YES.

Introduce a bogus table containing two columns: record1,record2.

Then create an INSTEAD OF INSERT trigger on this table which simply adds the info to the other two tables.

When you execute one single statement 'INSERT INTO MyBogusTable (record1,record2) VALUES (1,2)' you will actually insert values into two different tables using one single statement.

Anyway, this is ugly and not recommended. It is stupid and baffling (had to use translate.google for this word).

But: It is one possibility to answer 'YES' to the question 'is it possible?'
Ok, calling a stored procedure is also 'one single statement', but...aehm... well.